# Parent update causes remount of context consumer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a wrapper component that creates a context consumer and passes the context value as a prop to a handler component. When the parent of the wrapper component updates, it's causing my handler component to remount instead of just update.

```
const Wrapper = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  class ContextHandler extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      // handle the context as a side effect
    }

    render() {
      const { data, children } = this.props;
      return (
        <div ref={ref} {...data}>{children}</div>
      );
    }
  }
  return (
    <Context.Consumer>
      {
        context => (
          <ContextHandler
            data={props}
            context={context}
          >
            {props.children}
          </ContextHandler>
        )
      }
    </Context.Consumer>
  );
});
```

I put the wrapper inside a parent component:

```
class Parent extends Component {

  state = {
    toggle: false
  }

  updateMe = () => {
    this.setState(({toggle}) => ({toggle: !toggle}))
  }

  render() {
    const { children, data } = this.props;
    return (
      <Wrapper
        onClick={this.updateMe}
        {...data}
        ref={me => this.node = me}
      >
        {children}
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

When I click on the `Wrapper` and cause an update in `Parent`, the `ContextHandler` component remounts, which causes its state to reset. It should just update/reconcile and maintain state.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you mean re-render instead of remount?

Comment: No I mean remount

Comment: This may also be due to using the forwardRef as a functionalComponent, You can try switching to a HOC in that case.

Comment: I do have ContextHandler inside ContextHandler, but I thought the point of using context is to be able to pass data through multiple levels without concern?

Comment: Also the context that's passed into ContextHandler never gets updated. It's only passed down once.

Comment: Can you demonstrate what you mean by switching the forwardRef to an HOC?

Comment: Can you please check here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components

Comment: Ahh I see now. So maybe the issue is that I am defining the ContextHandler inside the forwardRef functional component. I will try this.

Comment: Putting the ContextHandler definition outside of forwardRef seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ContextHandler` class is implemented within the render function of the Wrapper component which means that an entirely new instance will be created on each render. To fix your issue, pull the implementation of `ContextHandler` out of the render function for `Wrapper`.