# How to prevent rendering component when you update theme prop on ThemeProvider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I update color theme by updating `theme` prop on `ThemeProvider`. And one of by components has `Popper` and if I toggle it and dispatch changing `theme` prop the `Popper` disappears.

Nevertheless, it updates default color value. But I want to make `Popper` with no rerender to make it visible anyway

[image]

[image]

Demo is unavailable

Comment: don't fight re-rendering. fight(debug) remounting for component with `popper`. probably you will find some `key` with random value or [constructing component class on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55483564/parent-update-causes-remount-of-context-consumer) that causes remount.

Comment: @skyboyer I guess it prolly causes because of changing ThemeProvider value as no way to unmount Popper component

Comment: actually a lot of people use context explicitly or as part of `redux` or `material-ui`. I don't think all of them are loosing component's state once some value is updated. just add `componentWillUmount() { console.log('unmounted!') }` to component that renders `<popper>` to check this assumption.